# How to show the validation error in client side while using Next-auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to validate the user credentials with the MongoDB data. I'm getting response correctly. But if I enter the wrong username or password how do I make know the user in the UI by indicating it like "User not found" or "Password is incorrect" ?
How to make the validation using next-auth ?

My "app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js" file looks like

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "Username" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "text", placeholder: "Password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        try {
          const client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
          });
          const db = client.db("test");
          const user = await db
            .collection("users")
            .findOne({ username: credentials.username });

            if (!user) {
              throw new Error("User is not found!");
            }
  
            const checkPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
              credentials.password,
              user.password
            );
  
            if (!checkPassword) {
              throw new Error("Password is incorrect!");
            }
  
            return { id: 1, name: user.username };
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          user.error = error.message;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.